# How do you make a singleton in Racket?

Tags: singleton, racket

How do you make a value in Racket such that no other code could ever create a value `equal?` to that one?

The reason I want this is to signify a placeholder inside various other data structures. For example, suppose that we have a little collection of key-value attributes like this:

```
'((name . breakfast) (successor . lunch) (predecessor . placeholder))

(define (placeholder? x) (eq? x 'placeholder))
```

The intent is to signify that `breakfast`'s predecessor is currently unknown, so, temporarily, we put a placeholder in that slot. We'll fill it in with a real predecessor later. The above isn't quite correct, because there's no way to say that `breakfast`'s predecessor really is the symbol `'placeholder`. (Similarly for representing special things like "doesn't have one".) Something like this would fix this problem:

```
(define placeholder (make-unique-value)
(define (placeholder? x) (eq? x placeholder))

`((name . breakfast) (successor . lunch) (predecessor . ,placeholder))
```

Since `placeholder` is a special value, you can't inadvertently make another one by just making the symbol `'placeholder`. It would be nice if the unique `placeholder` value wouldn't be `equal?` to anything; that way, it could also serve as a key in hash tables—or anywhere. The point is that you shouldn't have to worry about "gotchas".

If making a unique value like `#t` or `#f` isn't the way to do this in Racket, I'd accept an answer that showed the Rackety way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this in Racket is to create a local, opaque struct and create a single instance of that structure type. Since structs are generative (that is, each evaluation of a `struct` form produces a completely unique structure type), this value is guaranteed to be unique.

The code to do this usually looks something like this:

```
(define placeholder
  (let ()
    (struct placeholder ())
    (placeholder)))
```

This creates a unique, opaque value in `placeholder`:

```
> placeholder
#<placeholder>
> (equal? placeholder placeholder)
#t
> (equal? placeholder #t)
#f
```

Answer (score 1):

With the use of [`gensym`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/symbols.html?q=gensym#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._gensym%29%29) you can create a system of unique values.

For instance:

```
#lang racket

(define placeholder-unique-prefix "#$#@")

(define (new-placeholder)
  (gensym placeholder-unique-prefix))

(define (placeholder? x)
  (and (symbol? x)
       (string-prefix? (symbol->string x) placeholder-unique-prefix)))

(define placeholder1 (new-placeholder))
(define placeholder2 (new-placeholder))

(define cons1 (cons 'a placeholder1))

(define cons2 (cons 'b placeholder2))

(eq? (cdr cons1) placeholder1)  =>  #t

(eq? (cdr cons2) placeholder1)  =>  #f

(placeholder? (cdr cons1))      =>  #t

(placeholder? (cdr cons2))      =>  #t
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought of a way to do it. It's probably workable but it bothers me.

```
(struct unique [])

(define placeholder (unique))
(define (placeholder? x) (eq? x placeholder))

(define not-applicable (unique))
(define (not-applicable? x) (eq? x not-applicable))

(equal? placeholder not-applicable) ; => #f
```

Something that bothers me is that the way it works is very subtle. It works by exploiting the fact that the struct definition is missing `#:transparent`. If you make `unique` transparent, then each `unique` is `equal?` to all others, which means they're not really unique:

```
(struct unique [] #:transparent)

(define placeholder (unique))
(define not-applicable (unique))

(equal? placeholder not-applicable) ; => #t
```

If possible, I'd like the meaning and validity of the code to be obvious on inspection.